# How can I use RestDocumentJsonService with POST/PATCH/DELETE?

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm using this code to create my own REST service to GET documents from a spesific view or a single document through the use of the built in Domino DAS services inn ExtLib.

```
package no.kjeilen.das.services;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.ibm.domino.services.ServiceEngine;
import com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.document.RestDocumentJsonService;
import com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.document.impl.DefaultDocumentParameters;
import com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.RestViewJsonService;
import com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.impl.DefaultViewParameters;

public class ArticlesViewService implements         com.ibm.xsp.extlib.services.servlet.ServiceFactory{

    public ServiceEngine createEngine(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws ServletException {

        String pathinfo = httpRequest.getPathInfo();
        String action = pathinfo.substring(pathinfo.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

        if(action.equals("all")){
            DefaultViewParameters p = new DefaultViewParameters();
            p.setViewName("articlesAll");
            p.setGlobalValues(DefaultViewParameters.GLOBAL_ALL);
            p.setSystemColumns(DefaultViewParameters.SYSCOL_ALL);
            p.setDefaultColumns(true);
            p.setStart(0);
            p.setCount(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            return new RestViewJsonService(httpRequest, httpResponse, p);

        }else{
            DefaultDocumentParameters p = new DefaultDocumentParameters();
            p.setSystemItems(DefaultDocumentParameters.SYS_ITEM_ALL);
            p.setGlobalValues(DefaultDocumentParameters.GLOBAL_ALL);
            p.setDefaultItems(true);
            p.setDocumentUnid(action);

            return new RestDocumentJsonService(httpRequest,httpResponse,p);

        }       
    }
}
```

I then have this class to handle the servlet routing :

```
package no.kjeilen.das.services;

import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.services.servlet.DefaultServiceFactory;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.services.servlet.DefaultServletFactory;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.services.servlet.ServiceFactory;

public class DASServletFactory extends DefaultServletFactory {

    private static ServiceFactory createFactory() {
        DefaultServiceFactory factory = new DefaultServiceFactory();
        factory.addFactory("artikler", new ArticlesViewService() );

        return factory;
    }

    public DASServletFactory() {

        super("services", "Extension Library Services Servlet",     createFactory());

    }
}
```

This allows me to call : http://{server}/{db}/xsp/services/artikler/all to GET all entries in the view through DAS or I can call : http://{server}/{db}/xsp/services/artikler/{docUNID} to GET a spesific document through DAS.

But, how can I use/extend this approach to also include support for POST/PATCH/DELETE ?

I can't seem to find any examples on that..

Any info / tips / code would be greatly appreciated !

Kind regards,
Petter Kjeilen

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the custom REST service, you can put your call into the doPOST, doPUT, doDELETE. I think you will need to use doPUT over a PATCH.

You can get the UNID of the document you want via a method here http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/DominoHerald/entry/get_the_unid_for_custom_rest_service_toget_method?lang=en_us

Here is a sample, granted it's in SSJS not Java like you are using, but where I'm coding in the event, you should be able to put in your method.

Does this help?

Cheers,
Brian